# Multiprocessing list of dictionaries dont process duplicate key, value pairs at the same time

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am new to multiprocessing and have hit an issue I'm unable to solve. I have a list of dictionaries that looks similar to this (with many more dictionaries), that have duplicate 'device_name' key, value pairs (i.e. - `'device_name': 'name1'`):

```
DEVICE_LIST = [{'device_name': 'name1', 'config': '!\nint  Gi1/0/10\n des TEST INT DESC\n!', 'job_id': 1, 'hostname': 'name1.device.com', 'ip': '1.1.1.1', 'ping_result': 'UP'}, {'device_name': 'name2', 'config': '!\nint  Gi1/0/10\n des TEST INT DESC\n!', 'job_id': 1, 'hostname': 'name2.device.com', 'ip': '2.2.2.2', 'ping_result': 'UP'},  {'device_name': 'name1', 'config': '!\nint  Gi1/0/11\n des TEST INT DESC\n!', 'job_id': 1, 'hostname': 'name1.device.com', 'ip': '1.1.1.1', 'ping_result': 'UP'}]
```

I am sending the dictionaries to a function that logs into the device and executes configuration changes and captures data related to that transaction. Currently I'm sending the list to the function using `pool.map` like this:

```
import multiprocessing.dummy as mp

# Set pool size
pool = mp.Pool(10)

# Send the device list to the function using
CONFIG_RESULTS = pool.map(config_function, DEVICE_LIST)
```

What I would like to accomplish is if the key, value pair `'device_name': 'name1'` is already being processed do not process any other instance of `'device_name': 'name1'` until the first one has finished, as I don't want two configuration activities happening on the same device at the same time. Any thoughts?

Comment: You could separate the list into multiple lists, grouping the same devices together. Then you could start separate processes, each with one list, each single threading through a list consisting of one device.

Comment: That's a great idea, I used that approach instead and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Used [quamrana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4834/quamrana)'s suggestion and the 'groupby' approach from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71821307/19746076) (that still isn't quite clear to me) to get it working.

```
DEVICE_LIST = [{'device_name': 'name1', 'config': '!\nint  Gi1/0/10\n des TEST INT DESC\n!', 'job_id': 1, 'hostname': 'name1.device.com', 'ip': '1.1.1.1', 'ping_result': 'UP'}, {'device_name': 'name2', 'config': '!\nint  Gi1/0/10\n des TEST INT DESC\n!', 'job_id': 1, 'hostname': 'name2.device.com', 'ip': '2.2.2.2', 'ping_result': 'UP'},  {'device_name': 'name1', 'config': '!\nint  Gi1/0/11\n des TEST INT DESC\n!', 'job_id': 1, 'hostname': 'name1.device.com', 'ip': '1.1.1.1', 'ping_result': 'UP'}]

def device_list_processing(list_in):
    # Create list to store each device config job result
    device_results = []
    # For each device job in the list pass to 'config_function' to run config job
    for job in list_in:
        device_results.append(config_function(job))

    return device_results


# Create lists of config jobs grouped by device_name to avoid multiple configs on the same device at the same time
GROUPED_LIST = []
for _, g in groupby(sorted(DEVICE_LIST, key=lambda k: k["device_name"]), lambda k: k["device_name"]):
    GROUPED_LIST.append(list(g))

# Send the lists of config jobs grouped by device to the list processing function
pool = mp.Pool(10)
GROUPED_RESULTS = pool.map(device_list_processing, GROUPED_LIST)
```